# ora-12705 cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

Tags: oracle

I have i'm installing oracle in machine 12c, while installing everything goes smoothly but when it reach to database creation it passes two step.

- cleaning up failed stat
- copying database file
- creating and starting oracle instance

on the last point (creating and starting oracle instance) it gives me following error:

```
ora-12705 cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
```

what I have tried is:

- set env variable in windows to NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
- and also I have go ahead and rename the register edited of NLS

those above point also mentioned in couple of search I did but still when I retry database creation I get same error all the time.

thanks for help

Comment: Have you got the rest of your environment variables set properly, e.g. ORACLE_HOME?

Comment: i'm installing this in windows so ORACLE_HOME is set to by default in windows, but still check it it's their

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/63216/ora-12705-cannot-access-nls-data-files-or-invalid-environment-specified

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone,

finally after trying many steps on changing registry and also environment variable in windows property, without any luck I ignored database creation during installation and proceed with installation without creating database.

after installation is done I manually created database by launching DBCA and all went well without any error in NLS_LANG.

hope this is helpful to someone else

regards